# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string in blade form text

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-8

```
<div class="form-group">
   {{Form::label('Name*')}}
   {{Form::text('name',['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter name'])}}
   <!-- get message by name -->
   @error('name') 
        <div  class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div> 
   @enderror
</div>
```

`{{Form::text('name',['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter name'])}}` in this line whenever I do not use `['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter name']` it works fine but after adding that array it will throw me the following error:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Answer (score 0):

I not sure this still exist in Laravel 8, but you can use `echo` instead of `{{}}` and you can `print_r()` or `var_dump()` the `Form::text('name',['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter name'])` to see the array structure and choose an appropriate way to show it.